# Como guardo un booleano al rotar la pantalla

Tags: android, kotlin

en mi código quiero obtener un número aleatorio y dependiendo del número generado aplicarle un color al fondo de la aplicación. 
El problema es que al rotar la pantalla se me genera otro número aleatorio. Encontré por internet que usando el `onSaveInstanceState` y el `onRestoreInstanceState` se guardaba en el *activity* y se restauraba después pero no me funciona.

¨¨ kotlin

```
    private var numAleatorio: Int? = null   //GENERA UN NÚMERO ALEATORIO
    private var generarColor: Boolean = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //  LLAMADA A LOS OBJETOS
        clInicio = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout_Inicio)
        tvJugadores = findViewById(R.id.textView_Jugadores)
        // ----

        if (numAleatorio==null && generarColor) {
            numAleatorio = null ?: (0..4).shuffled().first()
            obtenerColor(numAleatorio)
            generarColor=false
        }
        clInicio?.setBackgroundColor(darColor!!.toInt())
    }

    private fun obtenerColor (num: Int?) {
        when(numAleatorio) {   //Obtengo un número random y lo parseo a int
            0 -> {
                darColor = Color.parseColor("#FF5252")
                //tvJugadores?.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#115911")) PONER LOS BOTONES DEL COLOR COMPLEMENTARIO
            }

            1 -> {
                darColor = Color.parseColor("#FFFD6B")
                //tvJugadores?.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#5AE870"))
            }

            2 -> {
                darColor = Color.parseColor("#2D8FCC")
                //tvJugadores?.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#915A2F"))
            }

            3 -> {
                darColor = Color.parseColor("#21282E")
                //tvJugadores?.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E2921"))
            }

            4    -> {
                darColor = Color.parseColor("#FF9F1C")
                //tvJugadores?.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1CA7FF"))
            }
        }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        outState?.run {
            putBoolean("NUMRANDOM", false)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }


    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
         super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

         generarColor = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean("NUMRANDOM")
    }

}
¨¨
```

Comment: Estas definiendo un valor false fijo en : putBoolean("NUMRANDOM", false) por lo tanto siempre obtendrás un valor false, debes guardar el valor de la variable generarColor , agregué respuesta. @Joaquín

Comment: De verdad que no sé que hacer, se guarda todo el rato el boolean en false pero es llegar al principio del onCreate y el log me muestra que se ha cambiado a true.

Answer (score 0):

Esta casi bien lo que estas implementando, para guardar un estado, y recuperarlo, en caso de que la pantalla cambien de `portrait` a `landscape`, debes hacer esto:

**Para guardar:**

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    outState?.putBoolean("hola", false)
}
```

**Para restaurar:**

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

        val boleanValue = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean("hola")

        Toast.makeText(this, boleanValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  //<-- Solo para probar si funciono.
    }
```

Solo unos ligeros cambios a lo que estas haciendo, quitando ese `run` del `outState`, y luego recuperando el valor guardado, en mi ejemplo lo recupero en una nueva variable.

Y cuando vayas a guardar el booleano del estado, guarda la variable `generarColor`, no lo coloques en falso directamente ya que lo que te importa es el cambio de esa variable en especifica. Puedes guardar falso, y al recuperar igualarla a ese valor, pero si en el método, ya la estas poniendo en falso no hace falta que guardes falso en el outState. No se si me explico.

Comment: Gracias pero me sigue dando el mismo error, me carga el booleano en true y no en false que es como lo guardo en el savedInstanceState

Comment: me había equivocado, la había guardado el estado en en el `onCreate`, lo siento, como es un `Bundle` igual me equivoque en eso, ahora si, ya la edite, y la pruebo en mi `app` y funciona.

Comment: Te guarda el valor del boolean? a mi aún no y no encuentro el problema

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar la documentación con respecto al método [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=es#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

> Para guardar información de estado de instancia adicional para su
>   actividad, debe sobreescribir el método [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=es#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) y agregar pares
>   clave-valor (key-value) al objeto Bundle que se guarda en caso de que su actividad
>   se destruya inesperadamente. Si anula onSaveInstanceState(), debe
>   llamar a la implementación de la superclase si desea que la
>   implementación predeterminada guarde el estado de la jerarquía de
>   vistas.

---

En el caso de rotar también se destruye tu actividad.

Tu código es casí correcto, **el problema es que estas definiendo un valor `false` fijo en : `putBoolean("NUMRANDOM", false)` por lo tanto siempre obtendrás un valor `false`, debes de usar el valor de la variable `generarColor` para que guarde su último valor al rotar**.

```
  override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        outState?.run {
            putBoolean("NUMRANDOM", generarColor)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
```

---

Al cargar el método `onCreate()`, estas volviendo a cambiar el valor de `generarColor` a `false`, ya que `numAleatorio` es `null` y `generarColor` es `true` :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ...
    ...

    if (numAleatorio==null && generarColor) {
        ...
        ...
        generarColor=false
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: me ganaste xD..

Comment: Sigue sin ir. Me estoy volviendo loco. Tengo puestos Logs para ver qué vale el boolean en cada  punto del código y en todos lados se cambia a false menos al principio del onCreate que vuelve a valer true

Comment: Tienes que definir que es lo que desees realice tu aplicación, en este caso estas cambiando el valor de numAleatorio a false si al girar se tiene un valor true en este misma variable, revisa la actualización @Joaquín

Comment: Conforme se mete al if el generarColor cambia a false, lo cual quiere decir que ya hay un color generado y por tanto no quiero que genere más al girar la pantalla. Pero cuando la giras, genera otro. He puesto Logs para ver qué hacen las funciones y el valor de generarColor que había cambiado a false tras generar el color, vuelve a tener el valor de true.

Comment: también, según he leido el savedInstanceState del onCreate debería estar en null solo la primera vez que se ejecuta la aplicación. Después ya no, y a mi se me vuelve a poner en null

Comment: @Joaquín exacto, solo la primera vez, la segunda no, ya que estas sobreescribiendo onSaveInstanceState() y agregando valores.

Comment: @Jorgesys Lo que yo busco es que no sobreescriba el boleean y una vez entre al if se quede permanentemente en false